# JOINS or multiple queries

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have and `Orders` table and an `Order_Details` table.

I need to SELECT a single Order and all its associated details.

Is this most efficiently done using two Select statements (one for the order and one for the details) and thus two `SqlDataReaders` and then looping through both to fill my UI.

Example: 
1. `SELECT * FROM Orders Where orderid = 3`; //will return 1 record
Show results in UI.
2. `SELECT * FROM Order_Details Where orderid = 3;` //will return x records
Loop through results and show in list format in same UI

- OR -

Should I use one select statement and one `SqlDataReader` but of course I would be returning a lot of extra data in each row.

Example
1. `SELECT * FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Order_Details ON Order_Details.orderid = Orders.orderid WHERE Orders.orderid = 3`;

In the second case, I only hit the database once but each row will have data from both tables in it. I assume the first case is the way to go. Anyone have a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first case, it will have two problems.
1. It will have two round trips to the database which is not advisable which increases `Network traffic`. 
2. Consider you are filling both the results to a `datatable`. When the second query fails, then you have to apply logic in your `datatable` to identify which record is fetched from which table. For that you need to combine all in a `Transaction`.

```
SELECT * FROM Orders Where orderid = 3;
SELECT * FROM Order_Details Where orderid = 3;
```

Its better you use the second way since only one round trip will be there. There won't be much problem in using `LEFT JOIN`; make sure that you tables have proper `Indexes`.

```
SELECT * FROM Orders 
LEFT JOIN Order_Details ON Order_Details.orderid = Orders.orderid 
WHERE  Orders.orderid = 3;
```

**EDIT :**

Consider a man who need to pick some boxes from two trains. He need to pick a box with number `3` from `Train1` and he need to pick some boxes from `Train2` with the numbers `3a`,`3b` etc which are ordered in ascending/descending order.

He need to cross the city which has high traffic to reach the railway station. What happens if he pick a box with number `3` from `Train1`, go to his house, drop the box there, come back to railway station to pick boxes from `Train2` with the numbers `3a`,`3b` etc and again return home to drop the `3a`,`3b` boxes?

He need to spend too much time since there is high traffic. It won't be a big problem if his house is near to railway station and he is traveling in off-peak time.

```
So coming to your tables - Why we need such round trips? 
It would be good if you do it in one query.
```

Now consider there are more than 50 boxes to pick from railway station. In that case, it will take some more time to load the boxes into his vehicle.

```
So coming to your tables - The more number of columns 
you select in the select query, the more time it will take. 
For that also single query is advisable.
```

Comment: Thanks Sarath. What about the fact that each Order_Detail row will contain all of the Order data as well. If I need to fetch 50 columns of Order data that is 50 columns of extra data for each Order_Detail row. Is that preferable to one extra database query.